# Wait for input while running

Tags: c++, game-engine, iostream, cin

I am trying to create a game with a c++ Console Application

My goal is to have my `do .. while()` running while waiting for a response.
It should keep displaying "..O.." until the "a" key is pressed and then it displays instead ".O..." or when the "d" key is pressed shows "...O."
My problem is i cant use `cin` or `getline` without pausing the application to wait for input.

So is there a way for to do something like a loop where if a value is not returned by `cin` in 10 milliseconds it prints "..O.." ?
I don't want the program to keep waiting for input, maybe like a `Sleep(10)`  between each `cin` ...

My Idea of how it should look:

```
void out()
{
    int x;
    string key;
    do {
        cin >> key;
        //insert here something like break; that will
        //stop waiting for input after 10 milliseconds.
        system("cls");
        if (key != "a" && key != "d") {
            cout << "..O..";
        }
        else {
            if (key == "a") {
                cout << ".O..." << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (key == "d") {
                    cout << "...O." << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "..O..";
                }
            }
        }
    } while (x == 0);
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll more than likely need to put your input on another thread. I recommend reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350909/taking-input-over-standard-i-o-in-multithreaded-application) and seeing if it'll help.

Comment: @Root0x
I read the link, but i have no idea how to do multi threading or even threading to begin with.
Perhaps send me a link clarifying what are them and how they work?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is to implement `GetAsyncKeyState()` which uses virtual key codes to check if a key is pressed.

The code would look like this:

```cpp
bool end = false;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << "..O..";

        cin >> key; //output will remain same as long as no input

        system("cls");
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) {
           cout << ".O..." << endl;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) {
           cout << "...O." << endl;
        }

    } while (!end); //remember to add a way to end the loop.
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate

List of Virtual Key Codes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: OK but this is Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem if no input is provided app must be in an initial position, so with some reordering

```
void out()
{
    int x;
    string key;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << "..O..";

        cin >> key; //output will remain same as long as no input

        system("cls");
        if (key == "a") {
           cout << ".O..." << endl;
        }
        else if (key == "d") {
           cout << "...O." << endl;
        }

    } while (x == 0);
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You.
I'm thinking if i do `if (key == key) {std::cout << "..O.." << endl;` so that if no key is present it reverts.

I can't thank you enough :D

Comment: @PhonedLeek25RedstoneWorks, You're welcomed :), honestly i didnt understand your comment.

Comment: I Just tried it and it failed, it still waited for an input..
I want the program to automatically skip the cin if after for example milliseconds pass and no input was received

Comment: btw i cant mention you due to the space so what do i do?
it doesn't fix it
I tried running it and it still waited for input every time. Read my last comment.
Sorry though :/

Though you can answer again and i will accept it if it works :D
would be great if you put in your answer anything related to threading